# Poor database design

Tags: sql, database

I am developing a system where the previous developer liked to hold multiple values in single cells.  Please see the DDL below:

```
create table visits (id int, values varchar(100))     

INSERT INTO visits values (1, '01/01/2000, 1')
INSERT INTO visits values (2, '01/01/2000, 2')
INSERT INTO visits values (3, '01/01/2000, 3')
```

Line 1 says that on 01/01/2000 customer 1 visited the store.  Line 2 says that on 01/01/2000, customer 2 visited the store etc....

I know this is poor.  I cannot think of a reasonable way of resolving this because the application has lots of arrays that split the contents of 'values'.  I would like to to this:

```
create table visits (id int, visitdate datetime, customerid int)
```

However, doing this causes errors because the arrays that split the values column only contain one value instead of two.  I believe I have to refactor the entire code base to get around this i.e. removing the arrays.  However, is there another way around this?

Comment: Add the new columns for date and customerid to the visits table. Moving forward, start inserting into the new columns, while still inserting the  previous column.. Then you can add a function that will use the new columns.

Comment: You also mentioned that there are many methods to get the data as an array... try to refactor so that you have one function that parses the data from the visits table

Comment: Clearly you will need this book: http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Databases-Evolutionary-Addison-Wesley-ebook/dp/B001QAP36E/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1372109272&sr=1-1&keywords=refactoring+databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a SQL View's  with Insert,  Update and Delete triggers.   The views Select statement concatenates a refactored  table  to  provide a  single 'values'  column.  The refactored table  can be properly normalized  with  atomically valued columns.

The views Insert  and Update  statement has a function to convert the old single values column to
individual columns.  The Delete of  a view deletes the underlying  base table row.

So  SQL Views provide you a layer of isolation and encapsulation so you don't need to refactor legacy code. The Refactoring, can take place as required on  a incremental basis.  The performance should be comparable using views.  The SQL optimizer will take care of that. The likely overhead are the functions to concatenate and de-concatenate the values.

With refactored tables, having  atomically  valued columns allows you create more selective indexes.
They can be used to speed  up some key queries.

Comment: Thanks. This would mean that information would be stored in two places?

Comment: No,  the data is only stored in one place. That's in the refactored table columns. A view stores no data.  When the view is queried the via a Select statement  the data is combined into a single columns by the SQL run-time using a stored proc.  So the data for the view is only materialized during the SQL transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Add new columns for the date and int, keep the old string column but change the update and insert code to maintain the new columns.

Then you have to refactor all the insert/update code to include the new columns.

To support legacy 'Split' code :
If you're using SQL 2005 or later you could replace the "Values" column with a "Computed column". If not you could create a view which has the extra "Values" column, and delete "values" from the real table.

[Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the reference to calculated fields.  Thanks.  Would you ever do this?

Comment: personally no. I work with Oracle & MS-SQL at the moment and it's a bit specific, so I'd either go with the view to support any old code, or I'd  load the rows into a simple classes. Then embed the split functionality in those. Once all the references are wrapped up in classes with some tests - I'd refactor the split stuff away

Comment: Why would  do this way? Duplicating data in the row by adding new columns is asking for integrity issues. All applications have to maintain the data in two columns to maintain compatibility and integrity.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intention. The idea was to refactor in stages. The end goal is always to remove the original string column. But you may need different approaches to support the original functionality during the refactoring process